# How can I view/edit Minecraft's level.dat file and other data files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft saves a lot of data in a file called [level.dat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alpha_Level_Format#level.dat_Format). What can I use to edit this? When I try to open it in Notepad++ all I get is a bunch of random symbols...          `æ&$+¿[w.ÜŠÖÄŸ¶…9É2þ`

Comment: I don't know what you are looking to do with level.dat, but to edit a map, you could use MCEdit. To edit your inventory there is also InvEdit.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Minecraft's data files are in a proprietary file format called [NBT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format) (**n**amed **b**inary **t**ag).

You're gonna need an editor specifically designed to open these, such as [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) (runs on Windows, Linux, Mac).

There is also the appropriately named [NBTedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/), but apparently it is no longer being updated and the author himself recommends NBTExplorer.

Comment: I prefer [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/). Just thought I'd share it for completeness. EDIT: Sorry, but I didn't notice how old this question is :/

Comment: @Lars Yep. When I answered this question, NBTExplorer didn't even exist. Thanks for the heads up though, it does appear to be the best option now.

Comment: For anyone else on Arch Linux: Install `mono`, run `mono path/to/NBTExplorer.exe`, open your `saves` directory, open `level.dat` and then `Data`, set `allowCommands` to `1`, save. Bish bosh.

Comment: Please note that NBTExplorer is no longer being updated. If you would like something that is kept up to date you may wish to use [Tryashtar's NBT Studio](https://github.com/tryashtar/nbt-studio).

Answer (score 3):

You can open it with WinRAR or Windows Explorer, then edit the file inside with Wordpad, Notepad, or any other program.

The file contains the /gamerule's and the properties like: Cheats, your Seed, the directory of all the world files, the game mode, and more.

But I have not edited it this way though, I just viewed it.
So if it breaks your world, then it's not my fault.

So the best way to edit it is NBTExplorer.

Answer (score 3):

The link provided by ShadowPlays is now broken, but the tool it was leading to is still around. It's called WebNBT, and can (at this point) be found here:

https://irath96.github.io/webNBT/

If the link doesn't work for you, try googling webnbt, that's how I found the new link

Answer (score 1):

Open it with webNBT Or NBTexplorer and see for yourself.

It's your world files basically, your playerdata and stuff.