# How can I find the actual seed code for my map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When a map is created randomly, how can we find the seed that it has generated ?

I want to find some cool map in single player and when I'll find one, I want to get that seed and create it on my SMP server.

Comment: In 1.8 they are going to implement the ability to see the level seed by pressing F3

Comment: @ProSay Having played the 1.8 pre-release, I can confirm that. You should make it an answer.

Comment: but he is kinda talking about 1.7...heck

Comment: @ProSay Not by number he isn't. When Minecraft is updated, you'll notice questions here tend to get updated answers too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, it should not be marked as answer since it's in a future

Comment: Small update: I'm currently playing 1.8.8 and when the debug overlay is called (by pressing F3) I cannot see any number that even remotely resembles a seed not to mention that there is no label that indicates its location on the screen.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In 1.3 and above you can type `/seed` into the console to view it.

However, this is not as good because usually you want the world seed to create another world like it, to share with a friend, and you can't copy/paste it.

For pre-1.3 versions (and for if you want easy copy/paste) go to [seedscope.net](http://seedscope.net), then upload your `level.dat` file, and it will show you your seed.

Comment: Ah, *where* in the F3 screen is it? Is the feature still in version 1.3.2? I'm not seeing it, for some reason.

Comment: @Cyclops Server admins have an option to hide the seed from the debug screen. (This avoids the problem of players scouting the map in single-player.) Are you on a multiplayer server?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, although I'm playing single-player, as I understand it - version 1.3 switched the code to pure multi-player, and faking single-player. Does that mean the seed is hidden by default? Is there any way to unhide it? Wups - I just noticed that the answer was edited to show shift-F3. I'll have to try that when I get home.

Comment: @Cyclops Ahah! [As of 1.3](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Seed_%28level_generation%29#Determining_the_seed) it no longer displays on the debug screen. Instead, enter `/seed` into the chat console (opened with `/`). This doesn't require cheats enabled to work, thankfully.

Answer (score 8):

If you already have the [Single Player Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-173-single-player-commands-v2111-new-update/) mod installed, it's extremely easy to find the seed of your world. Typing the command `/world seed` will print the seed of your world to the console.

Answer (score 6):

Without mods or websites, you can [view your level.dat file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/how-can-i-view-edit-minecrafts-level-dat-file) using a program like [NBTedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/).  Your level.dat file contains your seed.

Comment: So, which are the property containing the seed?

Answer (score 5):

In Beta-1.8 they are going to implement the ability to see the level seed by pressing F3.

Comment: This has been done.

Comment: captain obvious look at the date i posted this answer.

Comment: Then why don't you say that? Not everyone would know that, *obviously*.

Comment: @ProSay Whoa, no need for the hostility. He was just pointing it out.

Comment: I think this has been removed again. I had to use the /seed

Comment: Note that this answer concerns Minecraft **Beta** 1.8, **not** Minecraft official release 1.8. The seed was added in 1.8-beta, and removed in 1.3-release. It was *not* re-added in 1.8-release.

Answer (score 2):

There is mod available designed to help you [find slime spawns](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/397835-find-slime-spawning-chunks/).  It updates the F3 display ti include the seed.  If you update your local client it will find the seed of both your local maps, and for maps on SMP servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the seed and edit it using the program MCEdit.