# How can I get a world's seed in Minecraft Beta 1.7.3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a world in Minecraft Beta 1.7.3 and I need it's seed. Please note that F3 or /seed doesn't work because these features are not in Beta 1.7.3. Are there any tricks or programs I could use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the actual seed code for my map?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/how-can-i-find-the-actual-seed-code-for-my-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use re-create button, then go to more options there you would see the seed of map you are playing. I am 100% sure that the button would be in 1.7.3, because I used to recreate maps in 1.7.2

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, the button is *not* in beta 1.7.3. You *can* re-create a beta world in a newer version though, to get the seed.

Comment: must have to do something with beta. because in 1.7.2 it is there.

Comment: Ahh... I see the confusion. Beta 1.7.3 is not the beta version of 1.7.3. It's version 1.7.3 of the Minecraft beta, which was before Minecraft's official 1.0.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the `level.dat` file to [MineAtlas.com](http://mineatlas.com/#c_whatseed).

It allows you to see the seed. [image]

Comment: This is not made for Beta 1.7.3, though.

Comment: @AskahKuwestion while it doesn't show the correct biomes, the *seed* is shown correctly.

Answer (score -2):

In 1.3 and above you can type `/seed` into the console to view it.

Comment: Beta 1.7.3 does not have this.