# Where does the game store scoreboard information?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I restarted my server last night, and somehow the scoreboards have all been deleted. Does anyone know in which file they're stored in, and I can try restoring that from a backup? The server is about 6 GB, so I'm hesitant to upload the backup I took last night (especially considering what the start/stop just did).

In the meantime, I can try making them again, but there are so many, it might not be possible (it's a public server and there are a lot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. It was `./data/scoreboard.dat` inside the world save folder.

Comment: [In case anyone else stumbles across this question and wonders how to read the file](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27466/how-can-i-view-edit-minecrafts-level-dat-file-and-other-data-files)